# PHP no response data coming

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
           if($_POST['uniq']){

            $st = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_friends WHERE (send_to=:uniq OR send_from=:Uniq) AND (send_to=:Uniq OR send_from=:uniq) AND clearence='1'");
            $st->bindParam("Uniq", $friend);
            $st->bindParam("uniq" , $uniq);
            $st->execute();

            if($st->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                echo 'friend';
            }

            $st1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_friends WHERE send_to=:uniq AND send_from=:Uniq AND clearence='0'");
            $st1->bindParam("Uniq", $friend);
            $st1->bindParam("uniq" , $uniq);
            $st1->execute();

            if($st1->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                echo 'uncleared';
            }
 }else{
echo 'Something Went Wrong!';
}
```

No response data coming back but the the parameters sending successfully by ajax request.

Comment: Not all paths lead to output: If no rows are found for either query, you will get nothing back.

Comment: what do u mean by mutual exclusive and the :uniq and :Uniq are not equal

Comment: Can you try renaming one of the bind parameters, not sure if placeholders are case sensitive so Uniq and uniq may be the same field.